# why undefined returns in getElementByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom

I use below code to get the count of `p` tags in my html document.I have 2 `p` tags, but this code returns `"undefined"` for me :

```
document.write(document.getElementsByTagName('p').childElementCount);
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` returns **collection** of elements, you need to iterate over them

Comment: If you simply want the count, then use `.length`, not `.childElementCount`

Comment: You can try @Tushar's approach and see if it gives you the same result - but `.length` seems to satisfy your needs based on what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`childElementCount` returns the number of children an individual **`Node`** contains.

`document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a **`HTMLCollection`** - containing a collection of `Node` objects - which doesn't have a `childElementCount` property.

To get the total number of elements contained within a `HTMLCollection`, you can simply use its `length` property:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('p').length)
```

You can also do this, if you want to get the childElements:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
console.log(paragraphs[0].childElementCount);
```

The problem you're facing is that `getElementsByTagName` is returning an **array-like object** of paragraph elements. You need to get **one** of those elements and then you can call `childElementCount` on that element.

Paste the above in to the Chrome Console debugger and you should see a value output.

http://jsfiddle.net/bryanray/pwaj4yjd/

Comment: I can't get the count with `.childElementCount` here, right ?

Comment: Sure you can. Updated with an example.

Comment: It is not an "array" of elements, it is a live [HtmlCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Comment: It is an array-like object. Updated to be more specific.

Comment: The HTMLCollection interface represents a generic collection (array-like object) of elements (in document order) and offers methods and properties for selecting from the list. --- Why would you call it something more complicated than it needs to be? It's basically an array ... he wants to use it as an array. He's not trying to use HTMLCollection specific methods. He's using array methods (length).